# Given $v_1,v_2,v_3$ . Using two different methods, find all values of a for which the set $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} $ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $v_1=[1, 0, a^2  ],v_2=[0, a, 0 ]$ and $v_3=[1, 0, 1 ]$. Using two different methods, find all values of a for which the set $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent.

To help visualize it, I put it into a matrix
    $S=⎡⎣⎢a2010a2101⎤⎦⎥$

Since they are linearly independent, $Det$ can not be zero. Hence $Det = a(a^2-1)$

a can not be 0, 1, −1.

Comment: You've discussed one method to show that $S$ is linearly independent. Do you know of other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Write $$ mv_1+nv_2+kv_3=0$$

We have to find all $a$ such that all scalars $m,n,k$ are equal 0. We have now $$m+k=0\;\;\wedge \;\;na=0\;\;\wedge\;\;ma^2+k=0$$

Let find when those vectors are **not** linear independent:

Since $k=-m$ we get from last one $m(a^2-1)=0$

case 1: If $m=0$ then $n\ne 0$ so $a=0$.

case 2: If $m\ne 0$ then $a=\pm 1$

So for $a\in \{0,-1,1\}$ are not l. i., so for all other $a$ are linear independent.

Comment: You don't like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

We wish to find all values of $a$ so that the matrix
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & a & 0 \\
a^{2} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
has rank three. One quick way to do this is to consider the row-reduction
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & a & 0 \\
a^{2} & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\xrightarrow{R_3-a^2\cdot R_1\to R_3}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -a^{2} + 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that $A$ has rank three if and only if $a\neq0$ and $1-a^2\neq0$. That is, $A$ has rank three if and only if $a\notin\{-1, 0, 1\}$.